# Can't modify my <div> with CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a newbie into Wordpress and CSS+HTML styling,
by the way I own a Wordpress Theme (Sportexx) and I'd like to make my own menu with plain HTML and CSS.
Thanks to the visual composer, I added this code to the page:

```
<div id = "menutop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've also added this code to the style.css in my child theme (should remove bullets):

```
#menutop ul {list-style-type: none;}
```

but I still see the bullets in the list.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you provide URL to your website to have a look?

Comment: try ` #menutop ul {list-style: none !important;}`

Comment: I think your CSS is either overwritten by the themes CSS or it's not properly included in the theme

Comment: Try to enforce your css rules by using !important, `#menutop ul {list-style-type: none !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<style>
#menutop ul {list-style-type: none;}
</style>
<body>
<div id = "menutop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

I agree with @GOB in the comment above. Try installing [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) in FireFox where you can see if your CSS is being overridden.

Comment: We know it should work, the question is really whether the theme CSS is being overriden, or whether it's linked correctly, etc...

Comment: If I add the CSS in the main theme, it works fine, but doesn't if I put it in the Child.
That's definetly awkward since the Child Theme should be used for similar purposes...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10879472)

Comment: Thanks for the note @Akarienta. I couldn't post comments under the original post until just now (will correct for future).

Comment: @ProTheJoker: Are you able to be more specific with the CSS selector to override the parent theme? For example: #menutop ul.menu {list-style-type: none;} (or something). When troubleshooting items like this, I can see what CSS rules are being overridden in FireBug, and by what. Sometimes it's due to the parent theme being more specific with a selector, or because the parent css being loaded after the child css (the second would require additional discussion).

Comment: @ChristopherStevens I don't think it's the second one because, for example, functions.php of the child theme gets loaded after the parent's, so should do the same with CSS.
Maybe I should just install a Custom CSS plugin, even though it shouldn't be necessary.
Or modify the parent's CSS, but that's not good practice.
With firebug I see the parent's css loaded and nothing else

Comment: @ProTheJoker Do you have an online version we can look at?

Comment: @ChristopherStevens the name of the menu is "provamenutop" in this version:
http://www.ferrari.co.it/athletic/

Comment: Cool. I'm guessing the "sportexx" theme is a child theme of bootstrap, is that correct? At this time I don't see list-style-type: none; in your sportexx stylesheet. I'm still digging, but it's not being overridden as far as I can tell at this point. It's just not there. (double checking now)

Comment: To confirm, I don't see css anywhere that selects #provamenutop ul or anything related to #provamenutop via the link you sent (in any included css file). Someone could correct me if I'm wrong. Make sure the latest css file is uploaded and being included with the page. Clear any caches if that's an option (apologizes, been a while since using WordPress)

Comment: I see, but I can assure the file is there, loaded. Thanks a lot for your help, really.

Comment: No worries and thanks for your patience. Could you confirm where the css file is located for me online? I'll check again here in a few minutes.

Comment: wp-content/themes/sportexx-child/style.css should be the path of the file.

Comment: Cool, and I see it there. I don't see it being loaded on your site, nor anything sportexx-child related (only sportexx items without the "-child"). Forgive my gap of knowledge with child themes, but are you able to select the sportexx-child theme, or just sportexx in your WordPress settings?

Comment: I can select sportexx-child theme and that's what's active on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I just put it into the parent's style.css, so for now I'll stick to this solution.